# How do I listen to a single value inside a map within Sembast record?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, sembast

The documentation talks about listening to a record, but how do I listen to a single field inside that record? Assuming the record contains map.

Supposed I have a `User` class as follows:

```
class User {

final String uid; // used as key in Sembast
final String name;
bool isVerified;

/// Used to store data to Sembast
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
   'uid': uid,
   'name': name,
   'isVerified': isVerified,
};


}
```

When I save it locally like this:

```
final _store = stringMapStoreFactory.store('userStore');

// Store data:
await _store.record(user.uid).put(database, user.toMap());
```

Then somewhere in the page I want to listen to changes to `isVerified` field without fetching the whole `User` information. How do I do that?

Because `_store.record(user.uid).onSnapshot(database)` returns `Stream<RecordSnapshot>` of the whole data of that `User` class.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to firestore, you can only listen to a whole record change (or a query in a store) but not a single field change in a record. As a side note, fetching a "whole" record does not cost much, the record being already ready to use in memory.

Comment: Thank you Alex. You are right on, I was concerned with the 'cost'.